# How do to run java class in command Line (cmd)? (use classpath)

Tags: command-line, classpath, javac

I have java class in folder D:\myProjects\new_example:

```
package new_example;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

class MyClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(myClass.getMyDate()));
    } 
    public String getMyDate(){
       return "Hello";
    }
 }
```

How do to run this class in command Line (cmd) from disk D:? (If gson-2.2.4.jar is located: D:\library\gson-2.2.4.jar AND MyClass.java in D:\myProjects\new_example\MyClass.java), use classpath... How do to run it..?

Answer (score 1):

All you need: 
[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying this:

```
java -cp "jar_name.jar;libs/*" com.test.App

jar_name.jar : your jar name with .jar extension

libs/* : relative path to your dependency jars

com.test.App : Class with main(String[]) method
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the directory D:\myProjects:

java -cp  D:\library\gson-2.2.4.jar  new_example.MyClass